# Wire a ceiling fan in between two double/single pole switches to ONLY control the light with the fan controlled by a remote

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan

New ceiling fan comes with remote for light nd fan. want to utilize the two light switches to control the light only. And then use fan remote to control fan speed.

Comment: Please post the make and model number of your fan, and the wiring configuration where it will be mounted, and at each of the two switches. If you want to be able to run the fan even with the light switches off, you will need full-time hot at the fan unit in addition to switched hot from the switches.

Comment: Photos are always a big help.